# Pass character package name to help function

Tags: r

This works:

```
help(package="ggplot2")
```

This does not:

```
x <-"ggplot2"
help(package=x)

# Error in find.package(pkgName, lib.loc, verbose = verbose) : 
#   there is no package called ‘x’
```

How can I make it so that I can pass x to help to open the help page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the variable in parentheses:

```
x <-"ggplot2"
help(package=(x))
```

The help file for `?help` rather cryptically states for the package argument:

> To avoid a name being deparsed use e.g. (pkg_ref) (see the examples).

Comment: Perfect.  Should have asked a half hour ago before this drove me nuts.  You answered so quick I can't tick the check yet.

Comment: `library` has a `character.only` argument which can be used in this way (i.e. `library(x,character.only=TRUE)`: the parenthesis trick doesn't help for `library`); perhaps a wish-list request to R-devel to add such an argument for `help` would be in order ?

Answer (score 4):

Both `help` and `library` calls for interpreting "character" class input can be constructed with `do.call`

```
 x <-"ggplot2"
 do.call(library, list(x))
 do.call(help, list(package=x))
```

Comment: very generalizable to both +1

Comment: so, could one (clunkily) use `help(package=list(x))` ?

Comment: I thought I had tested and saw it fail, but it seems to succeed.